# Customize mini-cart - delete image and edit button

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, image, mini-cart, thumbnail

How to remove the picture and edit button from the mini-cart without using CSS

[image]

Expected Result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the template in your theme.

The original file is here:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

Copy to:

> app/design/frontend/your_vendor_name/your_theme_name/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

Line 10 is where the photo HTML starts. Edit link is around line 100.

After deleting these you will need to deploy your static content:

> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy